# How to make double working in OpenGL 4.1 on OS X ( Intel HD Graphics 5000 )?

Tags: opengl, shader

I've recently rebuild shaders for my program and it stopped "working" ( black screen ) on OS X ( El Capitan ), but **it's ok on Linux on GTX 660**.

I've tested it on another Apple hardware and **it worked on OS X on R9 395** ( but super slow, because of double ). So I suppose it's problem with my **Intel HD Graphics 5000**.

There are no shader compilation errors, and here is my shader code:

https://github.com/Marqin/YuriaViewer/blob/4241e384da0f27d26cbf5557518db905a9d40039/vertex.glsl

Keep in mind that this software worked on El Capitan with OpenGL 4.1 before shader rewrite. Here are my glfw hints:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```

My program also is checking for `GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64` and it's available on my Macbook ( Macbook Air 2013 mid ).

I've "debugged" it a little and it looks that `i` is always lesser than `vis` on OS X, that's why it's black.

I've also made a simple test - I've typed all uniform values in shader by hand and now it wasn't black, but I've got some gibberish on screen. Then I've changed every `dvec3` and `dvec2` to float versions and it showed nice fractal. So it looks like `double` is not working on OS X. But how can it be? It's saying that `GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64` is available and it even doesn't complain when I request it in vertex shader.

How can I make it work on OS X Macbook?

Comment: It's unfortunately not uncommon for drivers to contain bugs (or "features" to let Game X play optimally even though it doesn't use the API correctly)

Comment: I hope it's not driver bug, but my bug with padding in that struct.

Comment: and if you use std430 layout?

Comment: @ratchetfreak OS X only support OpenGL [4.1](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/) ( also, ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 is not supported on some 4.1 Mac Radeons, but it should be on my Intel ), and std430 was introduced in OpenGL 4.3

Comment: I've tested it now on one iMac, and it's working there ( but super slow ).

Comment: So it looks like this shader is not compatible with Intel cards or it's bug in OS X Intel driver.

Comment: @Marqin Could you convert your last comment into an aswer so we can get this post out of the unanswered queue?

Comment: @joojaa But frankly it's not valid answer. Some time ago I've reorganized my shader, changed types/order of  struct fields and now it "miraculously" work. And I still want to know why it was not working the old way - maybe I just made some error with padding? I cannot find that bug :/

Comment: @Marqin then answer that, the question does not contain your code so theres no way to verify your bug from this anyway.